# Не могу понять где ошибка в коде при написании таблицы умножения

Tags: python

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    for number_1 in numbers:
    for number_2 in numbers:
print(number_1, '*', number_2, '=', number_1 * number_2)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> IndentationError: unexpected indent

хотя отступы вроде правильно стоят

Comment: к сожалению в том виде, в котором вы предоставили вопрос трудно сказать насколько правильно вы указали отступы

Comment: интересно, кто плюсует подобные вопросы...

Comment: "хотя отступы вроде правильно стоят" - если python пишет что неправильно, значит нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отступы неправильные. Как я понял, вы хотели что-то вроде такого:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for number_1 in numbers:
    for number_2 in numbers:
        print(number_1, '*', number_2, '=', number_1 * number_2)
```

В Python отступы важны. Их нельзя "опускать".